# Find the number of ways a $2\times 8$ rectangle can be tiled with rectangular tiles of size $2 \times 1$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Find the number of ways a $2\times 8$ rectangle can be tiled with rectangular
>   tiles of size $2 \times 1$.

Since area of the rectangle is $16 m^2$ and area of each tile is $2 m^2$ so the total number of tiles is 8

But the answer is given to be $34$.
Where am I going wrong ?Please help.

Comment: You answered to 'how many tiles do you need to tile', not to the actal question

Answer (score 6):

Define $F(n)$ to be the number of ways for a $2$ by $n$ rectangle.

At one end of this rectangle you can either have a tile across the end or two tiles parallel to the 'longer' side.

If there is a tile across the end there will be $F(7)$ ways to complete the tiling. With the other arrangement there will be $F(6)$ ways to complete the tiling.

Therefore $F(8)=F(7)+F(6)$ and you can repeat this argument with $F(7)$ etc.

Using $F(1)=1$ and $F(2)=2$, you should  now be able to find a well known sequence leading to $F(8)$.

Answer (score 5):

You can derive this by induction.

Each $2\times n$ rectangle can either have horizontal or vertical tiles at its left-hand edge. The first becomes a $2\times n{-}2$ rectangle with two horizontal tiles on the left; the second becomes a  $2\times n{-}1$ rectangle with one vertical tile on the left.

So the tiling options for a $2\times n$ rectangle $t(n)$ sum the reduced rectangle options left from those two alternatives, $t(n)=t(n-2)+t(n-1)$. And $t(0)=1, t(1)=1$ so we have the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number): $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,\color{red}{34}$ as given.